# Send command from c# app to iphone

Tags: c#, objective-c, iphone, cydia, tweak

I am making an project that need to send command from c# app to iphone (in fact i need to get installed list app on iphone and send it to the c# app), but I do not know how to do this. As I search on google I figure out that I must make an client - server with iphone as server and c# app as client, then i will send command from c# app to iphone through socket in LAN (connect into one wifi). I must build an tweak on jailbroken iphone to connect with c# app.

More detail about what i need to do:

```
C# app will send command to iphone to get installed list app on iphone
Iphone will listen the command and send back data to c# app.
```

Now i have already build an c# application but do not know what to do next!, can you point me out this problem?

Comment: Are you working with jailbroken devices?  If not, you won't be able to get a list of installed apps.

Comment: @Avi yes i am working with jailbroken device